# Userform Listbox Change Event Fires Only Once No Matter How Many Clicks

Tags: vba, excel

Every time I test the following code, the change event only occurs once, no matter how many times I change the value in the listbox. The values are No and Yes and are populated when the userform initializes. I have changed the sub name to ListBox1_Click() as well, with the same result. Each time I test and change the value of the listbox, it'll run fine, then the next time I click it it will do nothing.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

If ListBox1.Selected(1) Then
    Me.Hide
    newForm.Show
    Me.Show
Else
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("A1") = ChrW(&H25A1)
        .Range("A2") = ChrW(&H25A1)
        .Range("A3") = ChrW(&H25A1)
        .Range("A4") = ChrW(&H25A1)
        .Range("A5") = ChrW(&H25A1)
        .Range("A6") = ChrW(&H25A1)
        .Range("A7") = ChrW(&H25A1)
        .Range("A8") = ChrW(&H25A1)
        .Range("A9") = ChrW(&H25A1)
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

In `ListBox1`, `Yes` and `No` are options populated when the userform it is in starts. Selecting `Yes` opens `newForm`, and when that userform closes the information entered into is saved (`Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")` to `.Range("A9")`). Selecting `No` clears the contents of those ranges. Selecting `Yes` again should bring up `newForm` for information to be entered again, and so on.

The following is the `newForm` code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 'Submit Button

With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    If ListBox1.Selected(0) Then
        .Range("A1") = ChrW(&H25A0)
    ElseIf ListBox1.Selected(1) Then
        .Range("A2") = ChrW(&H25A0)
    ElseIf ListBox1.Selected(2) Then
        .Range("A3") = ChrW(&H25A0)
    ElseIf ListBox1.Selected(3) Then
        .Range("A4") = ChrW(&H25A0)
    ElseIf ListBox1.Selected(4) Then
        .Range("A5") = ChrW(&H25A0)
    ElseIf ListBox1.Selected(5) Then
        .Range("A6") = ChrW(&H25A0)
    ElseIf ListBox1.Selected(6) Then
        .Range("A7") = ChrW(&H25A0)
    ElseIf ListBox1.Selected(7) Then
        .Range("A8") = ChrW(&H25A0)
    Else
        .Range("A9") = ChrW(&H25A0)
    End If
End With

Unload Me

End Sub
```

My issue is that while it works the first time `ListBox1` changes, any subsequent tries to change the value of `ListBox1` does not run the code (this is after `newForm` closes when `Yes` was selected).

**Step Guide**
Base Userform opens
`ListBox1` is populated with `Yes` and `No` as values.

A1) `Yes` is selected
A2) `newForm` opens
A3) Information is entered into `newForm`, `Submit` button is clicked
A4) Information is saved to `Sheet2` in ranges `A1` to `A9` as appropriate (`ChrW(&H25A0)`), `newForm` closes via `Unload Me`

B1) `No` is selected
B2) Information entered into `Sheet2` in ranges `A1` to `A9` is set to default (`ChrW(&H25A1)`)

Expected behavior after this is that it returns to steps A1 or B1 as selected, whereas nothing is happening after it runs through it the first time and any option is selected after that.

Using breakpoints shows that the code runs flawlessly, and as expected, during the first pass, then inexplicably will not run again after completion.

Comment: Please set a breakpoint: http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s196/breakpoints.htm and lt me know how far your code gets. I suspect the ListBox1.Selected(1) logic is getting fired all the time.

Comment: Exactly what is `"        "        "        "` supposed to be doing? `newForm` is an object, it should be `New`'d up, otherwise you're relying on state that's on the default instance. And yeah, place a breakpoint on the `If ... Then` line and see if the handler is running. Whether the handler runs and whether your logic gets triggered are two separate things.

Comment: @Absinthe The code works perfectly until it hits `Me.Show`, then it ends without doing anything else (I added `Exit Sub` under `Me.Show` and it doesn't highlight that; I don't know if that is by intention.) Any time after that that I click on the listbox, it does nothing, not even jump into the code.

Comment: @Mat'sMug The quotations are simply replacing `.Range("A2") = ChrW(&H25A1)` to `.Range("A8") = ChrW(&H25A1)`. Also, `newForm.Show` is where `newForm` is the name of the additional userform to open. Not sure if that was what was causing the confusion.

Comment: @Absinthe I further added `MsgBox ("Finished.")` between `Me.Show` and `Exit Sub`, and the MsgBox does not appear until _after_ I have closed the test userform (then the MsgBox appears before it takes me back into vba).

Comment: So... Are you surprised that `newForm.Show` is a blocking call? The form is modal by default, so execution will only resume in that procedure after the form has closed... Your question is incredibly unclear, please [edit] to clarify what you expect vs what you get.

Comment: @MCSythera that is normal behaviour, your form takes over execution of the code until it's closed

Comment: @Mat'sMug That is the behavior I want. My issue arises if there needs to be a change in the form _after_ the event is called the first time. `ListBox1` is populated at the start of the first userform, with `No` and `Yes`. `Yes` brings up `newForm`, which has a few questions and then when it is closed, saves the information entered. But if I wanted to change `Yes` to `No`, that _should_ clear the contents of the previous answers (the `Else` statement), and if I wanted to select `Yes` again, it should come up with `newForm`. But, any selection after the first time does not do anything.

Comment: You're going to have to [edit] your question and clarify exactly what you're expecting to happen, because it's extremely unclear and absolutely unanswerable at the moment.

Comment: @Absinthe I have added two additional lines to the original post explaining the problem, much the way I did in my previous comment.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I've made some additions to my edit.

Comment: Did you put breakpoints to see what was happening? You have no code that clears the contents of A1 and A9, and they're populated with constant values - your step B2 has no corresponding code in the snippet you posted. Also the code as posted cannot possibly compile, `"        "        "        "` isn't a legal instruction.

Comment: @Mat'sMug The quotations are simply replacing `.Range("A2") = ChrW(&H25A1)` to `.Range("A8") = ChrW(&H25A1)` within the code. `A1` to `A9` are cleared with `= ChrW(&H25A1)` (a blank square). Blank squares are their default value. `= ChrW(&H25A0)` (filled square) replaces these blank squares on `newForm` when the userform is exited based on the information provided on that userform. I have modified the original post to contain `A2` to `A8`. I also did try breakpoints, and it runs through fine the first time, stops at `Me.Show` and then does nothing the next time. See comments 3 and 5.

Comment: Ok look, I'm done wasting my time here and wish you the best of luck - the code you've got here does not clear anything (nothing sets the "filled square"), and you still haven't answered whether that else block runs if you put a breakpoint - "does not run the code" makes no sense - an event handler can't be deregistered magically in VBA. So put a breakpoint and step through your code and debug it; the code you're showing us obviously has nothing to do with the code you're looking at, so good luck.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I clarified `cleared` to `default`. No cell is a blank value. It starts as a blank square, is turned into a filled square depending on the information selected on `newForm`, and is turned back to a blank square when `No` is selected (clearing the filled squares). The If **and** Else blocks work fine _the first time the ListBox changes_; future ListBox changes _after the first time_ do nothing; they don't jump into the code, open no new userform, and set nothing to other values. After the first run through, which works fine, it simply stops working. I am sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: F9 to place a breakpoint. Put it on the FIRST EXECUTABLE STATEMENT of your event handler - that would be `If ListBox1.Selected(1) Then` - and it's only going to be hit when the listbox value *changes*. While in break mode verify the value of `ListBox1.Selected(1)` in the *immediate pane* - compare to what you expect and then try `ListBox1.ListIndex` and see if that makes more sense - "the code doesn't run" means nothing if you're not even bothering to put a breakpoint in the handler.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Clicking `No` runs through the `Else` statement as expected; clicking `Yes` runs through the `If` statement, opens the new userform, runs through that flawlessly, then returns to `Me.Show`. Returning to the userform and clicking `No` or `Yes` again does nothing; it doesn't run the code, doesn't run to the breakpoint, doesn't open VBA, doesn't change any values or open `newForm`; it does nothing at all after it runs through the first time. Every subsequent attempt to change the ListBox only changes the ListBox value, and does not even touch ListBox1_Change().

Comment: Tried handling another event, e.g. `ListBox1_Click()`?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Changing to `ListBox1.ListIndex = 1` showed the same result as `ListBox1.Selected(1)` in every test. If `No` was selected, it was `= 0` or `FALSE` and if `Yes` was selected it was `= 1` or `TRUE`, which was what was expected. I also tried changing `ListBox1_Change()` to `ListBox1_Click()` with no change. Does the same thing.

Comment: @Mat'sMug After a few more tests, it seems the `If` statement is breaking something, somewhere. If I click `No` first, _then_ `Yes`, both work fine and as intended. If I click `Yes` first, it does everything right, but I can't click `No` to clear afterwards. With `No` then `Yes`, upon returning to the original userform, both No and Yes show as selected, Yes cannot be selected again, and clicking No removes both selections; don't know if that is relevant to this error. Could it be the way `newForm` is ending, or the way the original userform reopens, or having `newForm` open this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is due to the fact that you call `Me.show` in *Modal* mode inside the event handler. Therefore, the event handler wont terminate unless the form itself is closed!

One solution would be to make the form non-modal

```
Me.show vbModeless
```

Another solution, if you need your forms to be always modal, you will need to be somehow "implicit": let the event handler *"terminate"* before undertaking the activity it is supposed to achieve. How to do that? By using `Application.Ontime`. This way of launching an activity lets the current procedure (your event handler) terminate before the activity is actually started.

**Implementation**

Put this code in a standard module:

```
Public Sub showSubForm()
    ParentForm.Hide ' <-- Put the actual code name of your parent form here
    newForm.show
    ParentForm.show ' <-- and here
End Sub
```

Then your handler should be like this:

```
If ListBox1.Selected(1) Then
    ' Launch subform **After** current handler finishes
    Application.OnTime Now, "showSubForm"
Else
    ' ... Rest of your routine
```

Comment: Perfectly simple. I had actually shown the original userform as `vbModeless` when it was opened at workbook initialization, mainly so I could access sheets and windows behind it while it was up. I figured it would open as `vbModeless` again, since it was only hidden and shown. Guess I was wrong. Thank you. I will have to change some of my other userforms that I hide instead of unloading with this in mind.

Comment: @MCSythera I see. Indeed you need to specify the modal mode *each time* you show a form. Glad to know that the problem is solved.